# can't print single item in a array

Tags: php, arrays

I don't know what's going on here.

I have this piece of code.

```
$data = getDataBySession($_COOKIE["session"],$db);
echo $data['name'];
print_r($data);
?>
```

function.php

```
function getDataBySession($session, PDO $db){
$query = "SELECT name, 
                 lastname
          FROM   users 
          WHERE  cookie = :id 
         "; 
      $query_params = array( 
          ':id' => $session
      ); 
      try{ 
      $stmt = $db->prepare($query); 
      $result = $stmt->execute($query_params); 
      } 
      catch(PDOException $ex){ 
      echo "Error > " .$ex->getMessage();
      }
    $dataUser = $stmt->fetchAll();
 return $dataUser;
}
```

`print_r` return this: `Array ( [0] => Array ( [name] => JOSE [lastname] => SUAREZ ) )`
But echo can't show it's content, nor print.
I don't belive it's the function because it returns the array, as you can see.
What am i doing wrong?

Comment: you're trying to echo `$data['nombre']` but this isn't a member of the array. Instead, try `echo $data[0]['name'];`.

Comment: it did work. it was because i returned an array from the function, and store it inside `$data` can't i make it work unidimentional?

Comment: The problem is within the definition of `getDataBySession` and not the code listed here. You'll have to modify the function to prevent the extra array.

Comment: i updated the code, with the function.

Comment: `$stmt->fetchAll()` is the culprit. Just use `$stmt->fetch()`. Also, people can edit the cookies on their computer to change their id number, so this is probably not the best way to go about retrieving who a person is.

Comment: It worked. Thanks, and don't worry `$_COOKIE["session"]` it's a random value stored in db and cookie, updated every time. So users can't actually know another user session. I think.